# Apache Commons CLI- What is the use of an argument name for an option?

Tags: command-line-interface, apache-commons

I'm familiarizing myself with the Apache Commons CLI library. OptionBuilder has this function where you can specify the arg name of an option. I am unclear on a situation where you would need an arg name. Any insight will be valuable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The "argument name" is only used for creating the help text. The only calls to the `getArgName()` method comes from the `HelpFormatter` class.